# Copy WAR to Application Server

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jar, war

Is there a way to automatically copy a WAR to a specified location after compiling it?

I use the NetBeans IDE together with Maven for my Java EE programming and was wondering whether there was a way within Maven to do that. I use Ubuntu 15.04 as OS. The way I currently get the WAR to the Application Server is typing a copy command after compiling:

```
scp /home/user/.m2/repository/com/myproj/myapp/1.0/myapp-1.0.war user@appserver:/opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/myapp.war
```

Comment: I think you should use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592823/how-to-execute-multiple-command-prompt-commands-using-maven-in-single-pom-xml

Comment: Is it to deploy it into a application server? Which of them, tomcat?

Comment: Thanks @facundofarias ! You're link was the way to the answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been working for me (Thank you @facundofarias):

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <executions>
                <execution><!-- Run our version calculation script -->
                    <id>Copy to Application Server</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/copy-to-appserver.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```